# How to get money record with most decimals in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, tostring

How can I get the money record from a column that has the most "active" decimal points. For example from the list (`0.01`, `0.0112` and `0.001`), the result should be `0.0112`.

My first thought was to convert to value to a `varchar` and get the record with the biggest length. But that didn't work since I had to specify to length if I didn't want it to get rounded. Here is the script:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(Value as DECIMAL(18, 6))) FROM Table
```

Comment: [`money`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is up to 4 decimal points to begin with. With the minus and the dot itself, the maximum `money` length is 21 (`-922337203685477.5808`), so you are safe to use the [default varchar length of 30](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks). Then you can only count the decimals after the `.`.

Comment: Between 0.12 and 0.002, which value do consider as having more decimals? What about 1234.5 and 1.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourValue MONEY, Explanation VARCHAR(150));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (0.0,'just zero')
,(0.1,'1 decimal in 0.1')
,(1.1,'1 decimal in 1.1')
,(-1.1,'1 decimal in -1.1')
,(123456789.1,'1 decimal in 123456789.1')
,(1.1234,'4 decimals in 1.1234')
,(1.12345,'4 decimals in 1.12345'); --5 is rounded implicitly
```

--You won't need all columns, I just placed them to visualize the intermediate steps

```
SELECT * 
      ,YourValue % 1 AS TrickWithModulo
      ,ABS(YourValue)-FLOOR(ABS(YourValue)) AS MathSolution
      ,CAST(ABS(YourValue) % 1 AS FLOAT) AS ConvertedToFloat_no_trailin_zeros
      ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST(ABS(YourValue) % 1 AS FLOAT)),3,100) JustTheDecimals
      ,LEN(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST(ABS(YourValue) % 1 AS FLOAT)),3,100)) Length_of_JustTheDecimals
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY Length_of_JustTheDecimals DESC;
```

The idea is

- Get the decimal part
- Use it as string
- Cut away the leading `0.`
- Get the length of the remaining digits
- Sort the result set to get the *longest* decimals on top